# Transaction Balance in bank account

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, class, local-storage

I have 2 methods, 1 is to get the initial amount and when I add credit I need to add it to the initial amount, somthing like paying my balance,  I am using this:

```
updateBalanceAmount(){
    let total = this.balance;
    let transactionType = document.getElementById("selectMovimiento").value;
    this.transaction.forEach(transactionAmount => {
        if (transactionType === 'credito') {
            total += Number(transactionAmount.amount)
        }
    });
    this.total = total
    document.querySelector('.available-amount').textContent = total
}
```

the second method is to update the balance when I add a transaction (buy something)

```
totalBalance(){
    let balance = parseFloat(document.querySelector('.balance-amount').textContent);
    let transactionType = document.getElementById("selectMovimiento").value;
    this.transaction.forEach(transactionAmount => {
        if (transactionType === 'gasto') {
            balance += Number(transactionAmount.amount)
        }
    });
    if (!isNaN(balance)) { // check if balance is not NaN
        this.balance = balance;
        document.querySelector('.balance-amount').textContent = balance;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if I can get this done with a better code or if you can see something wrong on it or if you can help me to understand how can I merge both methods to create just one. Thanks for your help

Comment: don't use UI as a data source. use a model to store the data and update the UI when the state changes (MVC, MVVM...)

Comment: Logically, you will have a list of transactions and whether each transaction is positive (increases the balance) or negative (decreases the balance). The balance is always computed at a given point in time - so you may want to cache the values at the points of time immediately after each transaction. In the beginning you will have the initial balance, after the first transaction you will have a new balance and so on. The last balance will be the current balance.